CoreData fault: Could not materialize Objective-C class named "Array"
Since upgrading to Xcode 16, when I compile I've been seeing my logs fill up with the following notification, warn, and error:
CoreData: fault: Could not materialize Objective-C class named "Array" from declared attribute value type "Array<String>" of attribute named categories

fault: Could not materialize Objective-C class named "Array" from declared attribute value type "Array<String>" of attribute named categories

CoreData: Could not materialize Objective-C class named "Array" from declared attribute value type "Array<String>" of attribute named categories

The first line shows up in white, the second in yellow, third in red.
I see it for both Array<String> and Array<UUID>, and each variable it complains about gives all three of those messages.
But I have multiple SwiftData models with Array and Array types and only a few of them are triggering this in the logs. Its possible it is just log spam that can be ignored but my app is super slow and crashes often on iOS18 (still great on iOS17!) so I can't rule this out yet.
Here also is the entire unexciting definition of the model (luckily I only have one model that has a categories parameter).
@Model
class CategoryGroupDetailsSD {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var name: String
    var categories: [String]
    var icon: String?
    var updatedAt: Date?

    init(id: String, name: String, categories: [String], icon: String?, updatedAt: Date?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.categories = categories
        self.icon = icon
        self.updatedAt = updatedAt
    }

    convenience init(item: CategoryGroupDetailsDTO) {
        self.init(
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name,
            categories: item.categories,
            icon: item.icon,
            updatedAt: item.updatedAt
        )
    }
}

extension CategoryGroupDetailsSD {
    func updateProperties(from other: CategoryGroupDetailsDTO) {
        self.name = other.name
        self.categories = other.categories
        self.icon = other.icon
        self.updatedAt = other.updatedAt
    }
}

Anyone know more about these errors? How I can diagnose or solve the problem?

Some arrays gives you the warnings/errors in the console but some don't, is there a  pattern in what the element types are for those arrays that generates the warnings? Primitive types, custom types?

No pattern that I can see. I'm only seeing it for [UUID] and [String]. I have 3 models with a [UUID] type and only one throws the error. Similarly, a handful of [String] types in my models and only 1 or 2 show this error.

I was able to reproduce this and to me it looks like the warning messages are printed when saving changes. I also replaced the string array with an array containing a custom type and then the warnings disappeared.

having the exact same issue, not sure if it causes issues or it's just normal xcode junk

@RaduUrsache I think it's mostly noise, when I tested with logging activated the actual save and update of my @Query after looked fine in the logs.

I've been squashing other bugs and my app is starting to perform well again despite these messages persisting so I'm starting to think @JoakimDanielson is right that these are just noise. I hate that there is no way to know for sure and even if we did that there is no way to silence them. Its too easy to miss actual important log info when its full of noise like this

In my case it happens with [Float]. Exactly the same. I'm also experiencing bad performance in macOS 15 (runs great in macOS 14). As op suggested the performance issues might come from other places, but the truth is these warnings do not help me in the least to maintain my sanity.  ;)

For SwiftData the easiest solution is to wrap the value type inside a struct and have it conform to Codable. Maybe not a solution that will suit everybody but it will remove the warnings

There is a related thread there too: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/761554

@JoakimDanielson if you are up for fleshing that out a bit, I think that would be a helpful answer to have on here. It seems that a lot of people are running into this so even i that only works for some, it would still be valuable.

When using SwiftData the best way forward today is probably to wrap the base type in a custom type (struct) instead that conforms to Codable.
struct Category: Codable {
    let name: String
}

and then
@Model
class CategoryGroupDetailsSD {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var name: String
    var categories: [Category]
    //... 
}

This might not be a solution for everyone but it will make the warnings go away. And on a personal note I think it can make the intention of the type become clearer and the code easier to read, using Category instead of  String like in this case.

Hi, I just tried this, but I'm still getting the same errors. I'm using a [UInt8] property instead of a string though, so that might be why?

Just to confirm, [String] is not supported directly on a model by SwiftData?

@Sentient I don’t think anyone said “not supported” but you do get a lot of annoying warnings if you use it. OP had some crashes but it’s not clear if they are related.

Also got similar error, but with CoreData, just changed attributeValueClassName to NSArray and cast it as a type I need. Here is more information: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/760985

I have the same issue with [String] and [Int]. However, I didn't make a new type for each property, but rather made both of them String (each value is separated with a comma) and now with the help of computed properties I can get the necessary value.
