Coredata Transformable properties no longer work after macOS 15 upgrade

fault: Could not materialize Objective-C class for declared attribute value class name "ContactContainer" of attribute named contactContainer CoreData: fault: Could not materialize Objective-C class for declared attribute value class name "ContactContainer" of attribute named contactContainer CoreData: Could not materialize Objective-C class for declared attribute value class name "ContactContainer" of attribute named contactContainer

Everything worked well until changing to new os release not sure if it's a changed setting or what. I have reinstalled the entire machine restarted cleared caches etc App no longer works. Can't login or open any windows nothing.
Transformer class
import Foundation

@objc(ContactValueTransformer)
public final class ContactValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: ContactValueTransformer.self))
    
    override public class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        ContactContainer.self
    }
    
    override public class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    override public func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let contact = value as? ContactContainer else { return nil }
        
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(contact)
            return data
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Failed to transform `ContactContainer` to `Data`")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    override public func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        if value == nil { return nil }
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
        
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(ContactContainer.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("Failed to transform `Data` to `ContactContainer`")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
        /// Registers the value transformer with `ValueTransformer`.
    public static func register() {
        let transformer = ContactValueTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }

}

Added Code for ContactContainer
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

public class ContactContainer: NSObject, Codable, ObservableObject {
    
    public var phones: [Phone] = [] {
        didSet {
            lastModified = .now
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    public var emails: [Email] = [] {
        didSet {
            lastModified = .now
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    public var addresses: [Address] = [] {
        didSet {
            lastModified = .now
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
        
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case phones
        case emails
        case addresses
        case lastModified
        case dateCreated
    }
    
    public private(set) var lastModified: Date
    public private(set) var dateCreated: Date

    public override init() {
        
        self.phones = []
        self.emails = []
        self.addresses = []
        self.lastModified = .now
        self.dateCreated = .now
        
        super.init()
    }
    
    public init(phone: Phone? = nil, email: Email? = nil, address: Address? = nil) {
        if let phone {
            self.phones = [phone]
        }
        if let email {
            self.emails = [email]
        }
        if let address {
            self.addresses = [address]
        }
        
        self.lastModified = .now
        self.dateCreated = .now
    }

    public init(phones: [Phone] = [], emails: [Email] = [], addresses: [Address] = []) {
        self.phones = phones
        self.emails = emails
        self.addresses = addresses
        self.lastModified = .now
        self.dateCreated = .now
    }
    
    public required init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.phones = try container.decode([Phone].self, forKey: .phones)
        self.emails = try container.decode([Email].self, forKey: .emails)
        self.addresses = try container.decode([Address].self, forKey: .addresses)
        self.lastModified = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .lastModified)
        self.dateCreated = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .dateCreated)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.phones, forKey: .phones)
        try container.encode(self.emails, forKey: .emails)
        try container.encode(self.addresses, forKey: .addresses)
        try container.encode(self.lastModified, forKey: .lastModified)
        try container.encode(self.dateCreated, forKey: .dateCreated)
    }
    
    public func hasMatch(for searchText: String) -> Bool {
        addresses.hasMatch(for: searchText)
        || phones.hasMatch(for: searchText)
        || emails.hasMatch(for: searchText)
    }
    
    public func copy() throws -> ContactContainer {
        try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: try JSONEncoder().encode(self))
    }
}

note: Phone Address and Email are basically the same Coddle protocols and implementation. Copy is to get the NSManagedObject to update the data.
COre Data model


I honestly don't know what to try I've deleted my matchbook pro and reinstalled from scratch tried time machine backups settings restart deleting container. I don't know what I expected, but I didn't expect two months of code down the drain.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79005211/coredata-fault-could-not-materialize-objective-c-class-named-array

I'm not sure what changed, but the solution was to declare each class @objc and make sure they all inherit from NSObject. I have no idea why that works, but it fixed the issue.

Transformable properties use NSCoding, which requires both of those things. I'm surprised it ever worked without them.
