Predicate too complex in Xcode 16
On Xcode 16, when trying to compile, getting error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"
(In expansion of macro 'Predicate' here)
Same code was compiling and working fine on Xcode 15. Removing any two of six parts divided by || compiles fine.
Code:
class FeaturesPredicate {
    class func predicate(_ enabledFeaturesName: String) -> Predicate<Caliber> {
        #Predicate {
            caliber in
            caliber.caliberData.featuresABCD.contains {
                feature in
                enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
            } || caliber.caliberData.featuresA.contains {
                feature in
                enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
            } || caliber.caliberData.featuresB.contains {
                feature in
                enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
            } || caliber.caliberData.featuresC.contains {
                feature in
                enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
            } || caliber.caliberData.featuresD.contains {
               feature in
               enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
            } || caliber.caliberData.featuresN.contains {
                feature in
                enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
            }
        }

Expanded predicate:
        Foundation.Predicate({
                    caliber in
            PredicateExpressions.build_Disjunction(
                lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Disjunction(
                    lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Disjunction(
                        lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Disjunction(
                            lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Disjunction(
                                lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
                                    PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                        root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(caliber),
                                            keyPath: \.caliberData
                                        ),
                                        keyPath: \.featuresABCD
                                    )
                                ) {
                        feature in
                                    PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                                        lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(enabledFeaturesName),
                                        rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(feature),
                                            keyPath: \.name
                                        )
                                    )
                                },
                                rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
                                    PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                        root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(caliber),
                                            keyPath: \.caliberData
                                        ),
                                        keyPath: \.featuresA
                                    )
                                ) {
                        feature in
                                    PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                                        lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(enabledFeaturesName),
                                        rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(feature),
                                            keyPath: \.name
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                            ),
                            rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
                                PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                    root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                        root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(caliber),
                                        keyPath: \.caliberData
                                    ),
                                    keyPath: \.featuresB
                                )
                            ) {
                        feature in
                                PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                                    lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(enabledFeaturesName),
                                    rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                        root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(feature),
                                        keyPath: \.name
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        ),
                        rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
                            PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                    root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(caliber),
                                    keyPath: \.caliberData
                                ),
                                keyPath: \.featuresC
                            )
                        ) {
                        feature in
                            PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                                lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(enabledFeaturesName),
                                rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                    root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(feature),
                                    keyPath: \.name
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    ),
                    rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
                        PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(caliber),
                                keyPath: \.caliberData
                            ),
                            keyPath: \.featuresD
                        )
                    ) {
                       feature in
                        PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                            lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(enabledFeaturesName),
                            rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                                root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(feature),
                                keyPath: \.name
                            )
                        )
                    }
                ),
                rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
                    PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                        root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(caliber),
                            keyPath: \.caliberData
                        ),
                        keyPath: \.featuresN
                    )
                ) {
                        feature in
                    PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                        lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(enabledFeaturesName),
                        rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(feature),
                            keyPath: \.name
                        )
                    )
                }
            )
        })


As the error message says, you should break it down into smaller pieces and then compose them.
Here I have made each of the contains calls its own separate Predicate, and I have also broken down the big disjunction into two halves.
class func predicate(_ enabledFeaturesName: String) -> Predicate<Caliber> {
    let featuresABCD = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        caliber.caliberData.featuresABCD.contains {
            feature in
            enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
        }
    }
    let featuresA = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        caliber.caliberData.featuresA.contains {
            feature in
            enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
        }
    }
    let featuresB = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        caliber.caliberData.featuresB.contains {
            feature in
            enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
        }
    }
    let featuresC = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        caliber.caliberData.featuresC.contains {
            feature in
            enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
        }
    }
    let featuresD = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        caliber.caliberData.featuresD.contains {
            feature in
            enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
        }
    }
    let featuresN = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        caliber.caliberData.featuresN.contains {
            feature in
            enabledFeaturesName == feature.name
        }
    }
    
    let firstHalf = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        featuresABCD.evaluate(caliber) ||
        featuresA.evaluate(caliber) ||
        featuresB.evaluate(caliber)
    }
    
    let secondHalf = #Predicate<Caliber> { caliber in
        featuresC.evaluate(caliber) ||
        featuresD.evaluate(caliber) ||
        featuresN.evaluate(caliber)
    }
    
    return #Predicate {
        caliber in
        firstHalf.evaluate(caliber) ||
        secondHalf.evaluate(caliber)
    }
}

This compiles very fast on my computer. You don't have to break it down this much if you just want it to successfully compile. You can combine firstHalf and secondHalf into a single #Predicate, but it takes considerably longer to compile on my computer.
Note that this uses build_evaluate which requires iOS 17.4.

I actually already did it exactly like this and it works. It seems unfortunately that other parts of SwiftData related code are not behaving the same on iOS 17 and iOS 18 :( For others - if you need to support pre 17.4, you can use this Swift Package: https://github.com/NoahKamara/CompoundPredicate

@DenissFedotovs I don't think it's a difference in iOS versions. My hypothesis is that Xcode 16 and/or Swift 6 compiler is just generally slower than Xcode 15/Swift 5 compiler. After all, there are more features added to them. What could have been type-checked within the timeout can no longer be in newer versions.

I will try to recheck later with faster computer if I will get one soon. There are other differences in iOS versions not related to this issue (like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79005211/coredata-fault-could-not-materialize-objective-c-class-named-array ). At least SwiftData store created with iOS 18 is not working as expected (as created with 17.5) for me :(. (I am using Swift 5 still.)
